# MongoDB aggregation - Match input parameter if provided else do not match

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I have a MongoDB aggregation query in which I have the following:

```
{ $match: { version: versionNumber }
```

The 'versionNumber' is an optional input parameter to the aggreagation. If this versionNumber is not provided, then I do not want this match to be performed.

Currently, if the versionNumber is not supplied, the match still happens and I get a blank query output.

Is there a way in Mongo to do this? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you want to skip a pipeline in aggregation. Is it so?

Comment: Yes, conditional skipping, I would say.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what will be the value in `versionNumber` when its not provided (optional), lets assume `versionNumber` will be any from `""` or `undefined` or `null`,

- if `versionNumebr` is not available then it will skip and when its available then it will match `$eq` condition
- you can add more values in array `[null, "", "undefined"]`, `0` zero or anything you wanted to skip

```
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $cond: [
          { $in: [versionNumber, [null, "", "undefined"]] },
          true,
          { $eq: ["$version", versionNumber] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

- if `versionNumebr` will be always single possible value `""` then you can use `$eq` instead of `$in`,

```
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: [versionNumber, ""] },
          true,
          { $eq: ["$version", versionNumber] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/437gV9rDl6u)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but $expr cannot be used with aggregation.

Comment: i.e. [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) does not accept [raw aggregation expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions). Instead, use a [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#op._S_expr) query expression to include aggregation expression in $match.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do that, yes, but it should be done in the application code.  When building the pipeline array to pass to the query, only include the `$match` stage if the necessary information is provided.

```
var pipeline=[]
if (versionNumber) pipeline.push( {$match: {version: versionNumber }} )
pipeline.push( ... Other Stages ... )

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```